# Result of overlapping clustering

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, data-analysis, unsupervised-learning

I'm using function `fcm` from Matlab for overlapping clustering. The output of this function is a matrix of size `kxn` with k being the number of clusters and n being the number of examples.

Now my problem is that how do I choose clusters for an example? For each example, I have scores for all clusters so I can easily find the best matched cluster, but what about other clusters?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the clustering algorithm, but you can probably interpret those soft clustering values as probabilities.  This gives two well-founded options for extracting a hard clustering:

1. Sample each point's cluster from its cluster distribution (a column in your kxn matrix).
2. Assign each point to its most probable cluster.  This corresponds to the MAP (max a posteriori) solution to the clustering problem.

Option 2 is probably the way to go - a single sample may not be a great representation of what's going on; with MAP, you're at least guaranteed to get something probable.

Comment: But what I want is to assign a data point several clusters if possible. How can I do it? For example, I can select the 3 most probable clusters, but I don't think it makes sense because we cannot treat all data points with the same way.

Comment: Ok, that's a little harder.  One way to go about it would be to assume that each cluster assignment is the marginal probability and sample them independently.